# How can I always initially hide a field when a form is first displayed?

Tags: css

I've got an jsp page. The page displays a lists of items.

These items can be 

- created by clicking a link, which displays a pop up form

- edited by clicking one of the items on the list

In the form, there is a field - compensation, that's either shown or hidden based on the values of other fields.

When a new item is created, I want compensation to *always* be hidden. 
But the problem is that depending on the state of that (compensation) field when the form was last shown, it's either shown, or hidden when the new item link is clicked.

For that field, I have the html/css as follows:

```
<tr id="compensation" style="display: none;"><td></td></tr>
```

(and then logic hides and shows the field as needed)

How can I always hide that field?

Comment: Are you already using jquery or something similiar? I would use something like that to reset the value of id like this `$("#compensation").hide();` after the new item is created.

Comment: @AndrewMacNaughton I am, but there's so many exit points of the form that I wanted to see if there was something that I could put in that would just always hide it instead when the form was entered. But you're right. Let me try that one. Thanks .. ..

Answer (score 0):

If you want the form field to always remain hidden, use:

```
<input type="hidden" name="compensation" value="<%= compensation %>" />
```

Comment: thanks; I only want it hidden when the form is first displayed, but able to be shown based on inputted values in other sections.